# Android: Bottom Navigation Bar recreating while switching to dark mode

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-layout, navigation

My bottom navigation bar recreates whenever I switch from light mode to dark mode and viceversa.
The scenario is this: I'm navigating to a whole new fragment which doesn't have the bottom navigation bar.. now, if I switch from light mode to dark mode, the bottom navigation bar appears when it shouldn't.

How should I deal with it?

Thank you everyone in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the app’s theme changes, App undergoes configuration changes and thus underlying activities recreate themselves.

Here is what [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/darktheme#config-changes) Says:

> When the app’s theme changes (either through the system setting or AppCompat) it triggers a uiMode configuration change. This means that Activities will be automatically **recreated**.

It means if at the start of `activity` you are setting a fragment that has no bottom navigation bar then you will end up seeing a fragment with no bottom navigation bar after changing the theme. That's what I can say with the little information I have from the question.

**I hope this helps :)**

Comment: Thank you, but how should I deal with it? Using uiMode in the manifest doesn't solve my problem. Whenever I switch theme it recreates the navigation bar while I don't need it. I just don't want the bottom nav to be created again

Comment: To solve this I need to know how you are managing the fragments & state. You can't restrict OS to not recreate activity! instead, you need to check how you are initing the Fragment and related bottom nav bar inside that activity! Behaviour should be consistent when start an Activity or by OS recreation.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `android:background` on your BottomNavigationView, change it to `app:itemBackground`